# How to use Custom Page Templates for hierarchical Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, page-attributes

I added custom post type to my website.

```
function any_posttype() {
    register_post_type(
        'any',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => __( 'Any' ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'Any' ),
            'all_items'          => __( ' All Blocks' ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Add New Block' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Block' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Block' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'Add New Block' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Block' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Block' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in trash' )
        ),

        'public'             => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
        'capability_type'    => 'page',
        'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'any'),
        'menu_position'      => 3


    )
);


}

add_action ('init', 'any_posttype');`
```

And I can't use Templates in Page Attributes. It doesn't exist. How to fix it? I tried create files any-{template}.php or {template}-any.php with that code inside:

```
/**
 * Template Name: Any
 */
```

but it didn't help me.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-templates-with-custom-post-type?replies=3#post-2850196